# Show on hover div center when screen resolution low

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a menu using div, which shows div when mouse over.
for the high resolutions it shows that div on the right side, but in low resolution i need to show this div to the left side or center,

here i attached a image of high resolution.
[image]

```
And here my codes and demo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xpDb/

please help  me to resolve this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding position relative and left: 0px will display the text all the way to the left. I modified this code in the demo and it worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/9xpDb/3/

.trigger:hover +div {

```
display: block;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
```

}

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 600px)" href="small-device.css" />
```

If you load the css into a separate stylesheet and then apply the link tag above, you can specify loading the new stylesheet you created for low resolutions (ex: width less than 600px)

Comment: no mate, i need that only on low resolution, like you seen on demo, it show div at the right side hidden, i need that to show in left side if the resolution is lpw

Comment: Edited my answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: i edited your answer and it's working nowm this should be max-device-width: 600px , thanks for help